# No reported language in a maven project

Tags: java, performance, maven-plugin, clover

I've been looking into the logs in the project I'm currently working on and trying to get rid of the warnings where most are related to missing versions, having dependencies duplicated, and one particular warning has me stumped:

> [INFO] --- maven-clover2-plugin:3.1.12.1:instrumentInternal (default)
>   @ project-name ---
>
> [WARNING] The reported language of this project is none, attempting to
>   instrument sources anyway
>
> [INFO] No Clover instrumentation done on source files
>   in:[~/Projects/projectOne/moduleOne/src/main/java] as no matching
>   sources files found (JAVA_LANGUAGE)

As far I understand, clover needs a language to instrument sources. I followed this guide: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER031/Clover-for-Maven+2+and+3+User%27s+Guide

I also specified the JDK in the configuration of this plugin but without success.

Answer (score 0):

[WARNING] The reported language of this project is none, attempting to instrument sources anyway

This is a warning printed by Clover when the following condition is met:
MavenProject.getArtifact().getArtifactHandler().getLanguage() != "java"

I suggest to ignore this warning (there's no option to disable it).

Comment: Update: I reduced severity of this message from WARNING to DEBUG. Change will be available in maven-clover2-plugin 4.0.5.

Comment: looks like the log/message does not reflect the behaviour/requirement in the code.  `If MavenProject.getArtifact().getArtifactHandler().getLanguage() != "java"`  then a more appropriate log/message would be __Java is not the reported language in this project or artifact X in the project__